# Drawing balls with replacement problem

Tags: probability

An urn contains three red balls and five white. Sample 6 times successively at random with replacement. what's the prob of exactly three white balls?

My answer: $\binom 6 3\cdot (3/8)^3 \cdot (3/8)^3$

Key: $\qquad\quad\binom 6 3\cdot (5/8)^3 \cdot (3/8)^3$

I do not understand why it's 5/8 since there would be only 3 white balls

Can anyone please clarify?

Comment: 5/8 chances for white ball in each pick

Answer (score 2):

The $\frac{5}{8}$ is in reference to the ratio of the number of white balls *in the urn*.

Do not confuse the number of white balls *in the urn* with the number of times that we draw a white ball.

*Five* white balls are in the urn.  We happen to ask the probability that the *number of times* that we draw white is three.

This is a prototypical example of a time where you use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: This!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use binomial distribution. 
Probability of white balls $ P(W) = \frac{5}{8} $ while red balls is $1 - P(W)$

In this case the probability of k white out of n is:

$$ P(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)^k \left(\frac{ 3}{8}\right)^ {n-k}$$

Comment: Formatting tip:  Typing `$\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)^k\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^{n - k}$` produces $\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)^k\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^{n - k}$.  You may find this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this, most of the time I'm looking syntax up there but it takes a while to get used.